# Insert forward slash character in the middle of text string

Tags: notepad++, regex

What wildcards should I use in Notepad++?

What I have:

`<text>BB13</text>`

What I want:

`<text>BB/13</text>`

Comment: Give more examples so it would be clear what you need. Is it the only search pattern that need to be replaced or do you have other ones ?

Comment: Pattern is constant and looks like this: '<text>XX00</text>'
Where:
XX - capital letters, 
00 - digits.
This is XML file.
Backspace always need to be inserted in same place. Between letters and digits. For example:
'<text>AA01</text>' to '<text>AA/01</text>'
'<text>AB17</text>' to '<text>AB/17</text>'

Comment: Find: ^(.{9}) Replace with: $1/ doesn't work because there are plenty of other text rows that should stay untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search/replace as regular expressions using :

Find what   : `(<text>[A-Z]+)([0-9]+)(<\/text>)`
Replace with: `\1\/\2\3`

Set check box 'Match case' if letters in the string `<text>XX00</text> Where: XX - capital letters` should match only uppercase characters `XX`